# Is it possible to insert video inside antd image.preview group

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

i tried to create a sort of media gallery for photos and videos. I tried a lot of free gallaries although i havent found a single one which supports video.
I tried to insert a video tag inside of ANTD image.preview group although as i expected it didn't work. It showed a video cover in gallery but no video.
I was wondering is it possible to do with ANTD or i just wasting time?

```
import { Image } from 'antd';

const App = () => (
 <div>
  <Image.PreviewGroup>
    <Image width={200} src="image1.svg" />
    <Image width={200} src="imag2.png" />
    <video width={200} src="video.mp4" />
  </Image.PreviewGroup>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure your implementation is correct, you pass a string as src in "video" element which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

> The URL.createObjectURL() static method creates a DOMString containing a URL representing the object given in the parameter.

If you have your video file in a [React state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

```
const [videoFile, setVideoFile] = useState();
```

You make can use of `createObjectUrl` directly in JSX:

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src={URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)}/>
</video>
```